# Sends results of FOR loop to text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I'm trying to capture the results of FOR loop in Windows command prompt and send to a text file.  I've tried adding `>> \\server\share\file.txt` at the end but isn't piping the results out.

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (C:\windows\temp\admins.txt) do net localgroup administrators microsoft\%%A /delete
```

Comment: Does it work if you pipe it to a local file, say `>> %temp%\temp31416.txt` and then copy that file to the share?

Comment: `>>` is not a pipe but redirection; anyway, I am pretty sure that UNC paths are not supported; check out `pushd` command which does...

Comment: UNC paths  are supported with redirection.  If you are running this from the cmd prompt then you need to use one percent symbol with your FOR variable.

Comment: I would put parentheses around the block to execute. `(net localgroup administrators microsoft\%%A /delete >>\\server\share\file.txt)`

Comment: I found on this on another blog, but the loop is going so fast, I not all user names are listed in the ouput. 
    1>> c:\windows\temp\tester.txt 2>&1